# Where to add initialization logic on ASP.NET MVC6?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

What's the recommended place to initialize things like background tasks, resource preloading and other application logic on ASP.NET MVC6?

I know this could be called in a `Startup` class but what bothers me is that it has nothing to do with `IApplicationBuilder`  or `IServicesCollection`, so it seems out of place.

Should I just add back a Global.asax and keep it on Application_Start?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Startup is definitely the place to do application startup logic.  Put that sort of thing in the constructor.  The Configure and ConfigureServices functions are simply special hooks that the environment looks for to wire up services and middleware.  That does not mean that those hooks are the purpose of Startup, only that those are one type of thing that may get bootstrapped there.

I would also recommend taking a look at creating your own services and middleware when appropriate.  You may be able to accomplish some of your objectives there.  For instance, you may be able to create a singleton service that loads resources once, but can then be injected into any controller that needs to access those resources.